# Parsing a C string and setting variables with values from the string

Tags: c, string

This post might be marked as a duplicate, but I did search online for this specific case and I couldn't find any examples similar to this.

How do I use `sscanf()` to parse a string and store all fields in various variables with some of the fields empty?

The following is a simplified version of my code:

```
// assume all vals are initialized with the correct type and memories allocated correctly

sscanf(data, "%d,%[^,],%[^,],%d,%[^,]", val1, val2, val3, val4, val5);
```

Note:

- `data` is a char pointer pointing to the string `"10101101,Water Level,,15,Collision"`
- All vals that stores string are calloc'd and all vals that store ints are initialized with 0

In the example above, `val1` and `val2` returns the correct results. However, since there is no value on the `val3` spot, the following vals starting from `val3` are being set to the incorrect result.

Is there a way to set `val3` with no value (or skip over the slot) and continue with `val4` and `val5`?

Assuming `val3` is an int value, results I would like to have are:

```
val1 = 10101101
val2 = "Water Level"
val3 = 0
val4 = 15
val5 = "Collision"
```

I'd really appreciate any help possible.

Comment: Use `strtok` to split the line at the commas, `strcpy` to copy the strings, and `strtol` to convert the numbers.

Comment: The problem is that `%[^,]` fails when the first character it reads is a `,`. You could split the `sscanf` to make it work the way you want to: `sscanf(data, "%d", val1); sscanf(data, ",%[^,]", val2);` etc

Comment: @user3386109 `strtok` will not produce empty strings. In the OP's case, it will output `10101101`, `Water Level`, `15` and `Collision` in each iteration of the loop without outputting the empty string in between.

Comment: @Spikatrix Good catch. The work around would be to count the leading commas before calling `strtok` again.

Comment: @Spikatrix And since turnabout is fair play... Your suggestion won't work either, because `sscanf` doesn't consume the input. It will simply start at the beginning of the string each time you call it.

Comment: Note that you're forgetting to put the `&` ampersand before using the `int` variables with `sscanf`.

Comment: @user3386109 Yeah, you're right. I missed that. I googled around and found `strsep` which I think can be used here.

Comment: @Spikatrix `strsep` is a good choice if available (it's not officially part of the C standard library). There's always `strcspn` which can be used to write your own `strsep` on systems that don't provide it.

Comment: Any ideas on what the function should look like? I tried different approaches but still can't figure out a way to solve it.

Comment: The good old inch-worm method using two pointers to work your way from comma to comma as you work down the string is always an option (there is nothing you can't parse with a pair [or triplet] of pointers...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to split a string into a fixed number of tokens. You want to allow empty tokens and you want to process the tokens further.

The standard tokenizing function, `strtok`, will consider continuous stretches of the separator character as a single separator, It wil also produce `NULL` tokens to signal the end of the string.

As so often in C, you can roll your own function. Let's write one that:

- separates strings at single separator tokens;
- makes the tokens pointers into the original string like `strtok`;
- "destroys" the string by overwriting the separators with null terminators;
- stores all token in a fixed-size array;
- stores empty strings after reaching the end, so that all elements of the array are guaranteed to be non-null for further processing.

That function could look like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void split(char *str, const char *sep, const char *res[], size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        size_t len = strcspn(str, sep);
        
        res[i] = str;
        
        str += len;
        if (*str) *str++ = '\0';
        
    }
}
```

Notes:

- The function modifies `str` so you cannot pass in a string literal. (You can `strcpy` the data to a buffer first to be safe.)
- The function `strcspn(s, c)` counts the numbers of characters in `s` up to the first occurrence of any of the characters in `c` or up the the end of the string.
- We overwrite and step over the end of the string only if it is a separator. That way we will produce repeated empty strings after the end has reached.

Here's a test for that function:

```
int main(void)
{    
    char data[80] = "10101101,Water Level,,15,Collision";
    size_t n = 5;
    const char *token[n];
    
    split(data, ",", token, n);
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("[%zu] \"%s\"\n", i, token[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would be worth noting a delimiter of `",\n"` would allow strings directly from `fgets()`, but a nice choice using `strcspn()`. You can actually use both `strspn()` and `strcspn()` to work down the string. (`strspn (str, ",")` would tell you the number of sequential commas and that number minus 1 provides the number of empty fields)